# how to implement JPA

Tags: gae-datastore

I have developed an application in Java that is registered on Google App Engine. I need to store some data on data store. But, I am completely unaware about its implementation.

Actually, I have implemented OAuth, so I want to store data of particular user who has logged in. Is it possible to separate out data stores for different users ?

Also, there is some quota limitation. How much data can we store for whole application ?

Comment: Hi @Setu ~ I would encourage you to keep questions limited to one per post. Both would make great individual answers. Can I talk you into splitting them and having two?

Answer (score 2):

a quick search in google gave me this:

- [Using JPA with App Engine](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview.html)
- [Quotas](http://code.google.com/intl/en-en/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Resources)

Also, in the datastore you can store only `entities`, this means that when you save some user data, it will be stored in the `Users` entity with all the other users data, what you have to do is implement relationships between entities like in a regular database (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.), check it out here:

- [Using the Datastore with JDO](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html)